# iPad html5 video with NO controls?

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, video, html5-video

This has been killing me all day, but I am not sure how to get a html5 video player working without the native controls.

I want no controls what-so-ever but if I don't include them, the video does not seem to want to play, even if I add some javascript below trying to force it to play, it works on iPhone and multiple browsers, but not iPad which is strange, any idea?

Here's some markup if it helps!

```
<video src="video.mp4" id="video" poster="image.jpg" onclick="this.play();"/></video>

$('#video').click(function(){
   document.getElementById('video').play();
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

iOS does not support the `autoplay` attribute of the video tag. It would also appear that you cannot use jQuery to bind to a click event from the video element (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfBmF/2/)).

A workaround is to position an invisible div over the video element and bind the click which plays the video to that (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfBmF/7/)):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="video-overlay"></div>
<video id="video" width="400" height="300">
      <source id='mp4'
        src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"
        type='video/mp4'>
      <source id='webm'
        src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm"
        type='video/webm'>
      <source id='ogv'
        src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv"
        type='video/ogg'>
</video>
```

**CSS:**

```
#video { border: 1px solid black; }
#video-overlay { position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 300px; z-index: 999;  }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#video-overlay').click(function(){
   document.getElementById('video').play();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clear reply, I will give this a spin and get back after ;))

Answer (score 8):

By design you can't autoplay video, but it's simple enough to remove the controls after playback has started, which I'm guessing is the effect you really want:

```
<video id="video" src="video.mp4" poster="image.jpg" preload="auto" onplaying="this.controls=false"/></video>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the `preload="auto"` does anything or not on an iPad, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: This fixed my issues!

Comment: This worked for me and I can even use jQuery to dynamically add `onplaying` prop to the tag if anyone is using some video player plugins that hides `video` tag

Answer (score 5):

I used this

```
<video id="video" controls=“true” width="300" height="250" poster="gray30x25.gif"  autoplay onplaying="this.controls=false">
```

`controls=“true”` - makes it work on ipad

`autoplay` - makes it autoplay except mobile

`onplaying="this.controls=false"` - removes the controls when playing

It autoplays on laptop, and works on iPad!
thanks Doin

Comment: `controls` is boolean. No need for `controls="true"` or `controls="false"`. If the attribute, in any form, is present, then will be true.

Answer (score 3):

The best I can do is play the video as soon as the user touches the screen to do anything, even scroll down the page.

```
function playVideoNow(e)
{
    document.getElementById('video').play();
    document.removeEventListener('touchstart', playVideoNow);
}

document.addEventListener('touchstart', playVideoNow, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now, iOS 6 supports the `autoplay` element on some devices.

Check http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/autoloop/ for reference.