# HTML5 Video // Completely Hide Controls

Tags: html, video

How Could I completely hide HTML5 video controls?

```
<video width="300" height="200" controls="false" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="video/supercoolvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

false didn't work -- how is this done?

Cheers.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Like this:

```
<video width="300" height="200" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="video/supercoolvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

`controls` is a [boolean attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes):

> Note: The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean
>   attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be
>   omitted altogether.

Comment: So technically this works; and I guess, is the answer. Though; removing 'Controls' within the HTML5 Video mark-up, kills the video on iPad; so am in need of another solution.

Comment: @1977 [This question is probably relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10856209/8655)

Comment: You could try to load the tag including the control attribute and remove it after pageload with some javascript: var video = document.getElementById('myvideo'); video.control = false;

Comment: `The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes`. talk about confusing.

Comment: @jammypeach The attributes are boolean because they have two states: they exist or they don't

Comment: @robertc that may be but it's also inconsistent with common markup syntax. if browsers manufacturers wanted to they could start checking if a value is defined and if that value is true or false and behave accordingly. once the feature hits critical mass we eliminate the issue.

Comment: @robertc ... the below link for "boolean attribute" is no longer available now. Please update the same ... `http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute`

Comment: 'true' and 'false' are allowed on boolean attributes, but both of those, and any other, are equivalent to 'true'. It is the presence of the attribute that determines its boolean value, not what is assigned to it.

Comment: "boolean attribute" is not the same as "attribute with boolean value". But I 100% agree that this is confusing as hell

Answer (score 67):

You could hide controls using CSS Pseudo Selectors like 
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g1rsasa3

```js
//For Firefox we have to handle it in JavaScript 
var vids = $("video"); 
$.each(vids, function(){
       this.controls = false; 
}); 
//Loop though all Video tags and set Controls as false

$("video").click(function() {
  //console.log(this); 
  if (this.paused) {
    this.play();
  } else {
    this.pause();
  }
});
```

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none;
}

/* Could Use thise as well for Individual Controls */
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {}

video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {}

video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {}

video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {}

video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Hiding HTML5 Video Controls using CSS Pseudo selectors -->

<video width="800" autoplay controls="false">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: This works great for Chrome but not Firefox. Do you have a cross-browser solution?

Comment: Need to remove them with CSS or JavaScript because I'm hacking something together and can't directly edit the video tag code

Comment: Hey Benny for Mozilla. You need to add vendor prefixed css for all of them like "-moz-media-controls-play-button" . Thanks

Comment: Tried adding the prefixes but it didn't work. Here is an updateed [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1rsasa3/588/) and here is the CSS I used `video::-webkit-media-controls, video::-moz-media-controls, video::-o-media-controls, video::-ms-media-controls {
  display: none !important;
}`

Comment: Benny, I checked in Mozilla document those vendor prefixed pseudo CSS is not available. You can handle this over JavaScript. Please see my code snippet. above . I have edited my original solution. "For Firefox we have to handle it in JavaScript " Thanks Good luck

Comment: Unfortunatley, that JS is not working in Firefox either.

Comment: It is working fine for me. Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/abidCharlotte49er/g1rsasa3

Comment: Ok that one works! Sorry I didn't realise I had to remove that second part of the JS. Thanks for your help. Upvoted this :)

Comment: I found what seems to be a complete list: https://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-7602.2.14.0.5/css/mediaControls.css.auto.html

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically show/hide any of these individual controls. For example: apply css video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {display: none;} initially to hide the current time control but when the video is played, show the current time control by updating the css class video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {/*display: none;*/}. Or apply a different css class which shows the current time. Thanks.

Comment: On a browser with JS disabled, even with no `controls` attribute, the controls will still be there (at least on Chromium/Safari browsers). Using `video::-webkit-media-controls` is an appropriate solution here!

Answer (score 52):

A simple solution is – just to ignore user interactions :-)

```
video {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This works except that the controls are shown on initial load.

Answer (score 11):

There are two ways to hide video tag controls

1. Remove the `controls` attribute from the video tag.
2. Add the css to the video tag

   ```
   video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
   display: none !important;
   opacity: 1 !important;}
   ```

Comment: This will only works for Chrome browser, I want this for all browsers.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, remove video's "controls" attribute.
For iOS, we could hide video's buildin play button by adding the following CSS pseudo selector:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Does not work on iOS in low power mode.

Answer (score 4):

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: I agree.  The simplest solution is to never put the attribute to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

This method worked in my case.

```
video=getElementsByTagName('video');
function removeControls(video){
  video.removeAttribute('controls');
}
window.onload=removeControls(video);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { initialiseMediaPlayer(); }, false);


function initialiseMediaPlayer() {

    mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('media-video');

    mediaPlayer.controls = false;

    mediaPlayer.addEventListener('volumechange', function(e) { 
        // Update the button to be mute/unmute
        if (mediaPlayer.muted) changeButtonType(muteBtn, 'unmute');
        else changeButtonType(muteBtn, 'mute');
    }, false);  
    mediaPlayer.addEventListener('ended', function() { this.pause(); }, false); 
}
```

Comment: <!--make from complete text <script src='media-player.js'></script> and put in same directory-->

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put 'playsinline' as attribute. If you put constrols="false" probably you still gonna get controls in mobile, and remember to put 'muted' also if you want the video to automatic plays.

```
<video width="300" height="200" playsinline autoplay muted>
    <source src="video/supercoolvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```