# How to create a animation for a webpage that's not flash or gif

Tags: flash, animation, web, embed, mp4

First off, I don't know much at all about video/animation, just keep that in mind ;) I know basic html. I help with my church's website, and they want to add an animated image on our website. The guy who made made it into a .mp4 but might be able to export it at something else. We don't want to use flash (not support by apple products, correct?) and he said a GIF would be choppy/not look good. The animation is of a tree growing from a seed to tree (just a short animation). Wondering if there's a way to display this so when they first visit the site, they see it in the top corner, the animation of the tree grow just once and its done and then show the grown tree. Is there a way to do this from his MP4? If I embed the MP4 it will have a play bar like a video right? and I don't want that.

Comment: Would embedding the video, but then hiding/disabling the control/play bar work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161516/html5-video-completely-hide-controls

Answer (score 0):

Exporting as '.gif' does not necessarily look ugly. (This depends on how many different colors are in use - animated gifs are limited to 256 color)

You might try [animated PNG](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animated_Portable_Network_Graphics)

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the mp4 then turn off the play bar with a bit of css