# How to disable or hide the native player in IOS, using Jquery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, html5-video

I am using video js for player. In IOS devices the native player is not hiding.
Added `webkit-playsinline` and `controls='false'` in `video` tag.

```
<video controls='false'  webkit-playsinline>
```

Tried the below code, it is not working.

```
::-webkit-media-controls {
   display:none !important;
}
```

The below code worked to hide native player controls, but the white         background of the native player still remains.

```
::-webkit-media-control-panel {
   display:none !important;
}
```

Please provide the solution how to hide the native control bar in IOS devices.

Comment: Do  not keep `controls` attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `controls='false'`

`controls` is a boolean attribute:

> Note: The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean
>   attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be
>   omitted altogether.

Source: [HTML5 Video // Completely Hide Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161516/html5-video-completely-hide-controls)