# HTML5 video - hide timeline

Tags: html, video, controls

i'm trying to hide timeline in video element.

It works for chrome:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {display:none;}
```

...but not in firefox and opera (i don't care about IE).

Help.
Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video // Completely Hide Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161516/html5-video-completely-hide-controls)

Comment: Remove `controls` from your `<video>` tag. Create own JS functions to control the tag.