# is there a javascript of jquery function to disable or remove timer from html video

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a video blog and i want to remove the timer or timeupdate that appears on the video along with other controls. I have searched but only got how to disable control but not the timer specific.

Comment: That depends entirely on the technology used to play the video.

Comment: What have you tried? How are you playing the videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a `<video>` object:

Chrome supports a [controlsList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/controlsList) attribute on the video tag, which allows you to hide some of the normal controls -- `nodownload, nofullscreen, and noremoteplayback` -- the timer is not among them, however, and this an experimental  and not widely supported feature.

There are also some [vendor-prefixed CSS rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36293084/3412322) you could use, including `::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display` -- again, though, this is browser-specific.

The only cross-browser way to handle this would be to hide the default controls completely (by omitting the `controls` attribute from the video tag, or setting `.controls = false` on the video element in JS) and implement your own set of custom controls which will handle interaction with the video via the javascript [Media API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), for example

```
video = document.getElementById('video');
video.controls = false;  // hide default controls

document.getElementById('customplaypausebutton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   if (video.paused || video.ended) video.play();
   else video.pause();
});
// etc for all other controls
```

This can end up being a substantial amount of work, but if it's worth it for you MDN has a [very detailed tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player) on how to do it.