# Hide/disabled forward and backward buttons for safari video player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to control the forward and backward buttons for safari video player but don't know how to call them. Like for play, you called 'play' event or 'pause' for pausing the video.
Worst case, if control is not happening, is there any way to hide or disabled this buttons?

I detect the safari browser and apply 'play' event, it's working fine but forward/backward not find anything at all.

`!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/)` this will allow to do modifications only for safari. Don't have much code right now. don't know what to show here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video // Completely Hide Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161516/html5-video-completely-hide-controls)

Comment: @NicoHaase it's not about hiding the whole control bar, the duplicate link you put. it's only for safari browser where forward and backward buttons comes built-in and there's not a single documentation for this like how to control them. if u have any duplicate for this, then please put that link, not html5 video control hide.

Comment: If you hide the controls completely does it also hide the forward and back button?

Comment: @cloned Yeah, it also hides the buttons cause those buttons also part of the control bar but i don't want to hide the controls completely, just for safari browser need to control it, if not happens, the need to disabled it or hide it which comes built-in. only for safari. Chrome don't have any such buttons.

Comment: You can only hide/show the complete controls. What you can do is hide complete controls and build your own set of buttons to control the videoplayer. But there is no way to show/hide specific buttons on a specific browser. Correct me if I'm wrong, I'd be also interested in this.