# html how to remove control bar in video tag inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I make live streaming video using webrtc.

You can see control bar in it because of video tag.

I want to remove video control tag in page. If you know about this, please help em.

Thanks to watching...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi just check your video code if there is any

> controls

word like that

```
<video src="../videos/test.mp4" autoplay controls></video>
```

then remove it to be like that

```
<video src="../videos/test.mp4" autoplay ></video>
```

Comment: as you know, video tag is placed in iframe. i can't change iframe content. I just can use obove url in iFrame.

Comment: try this post here may help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161516/html5-video-completely-hide-controls

Answer (score 1):

For removing the **controls**, add `controls=0` at the end of your url

```
<iframe width="840" id="dice-frame" height="478" src="15.164.215.4:5080/WebRTCAppEE/…?controls=0" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Another approach (if you want to hide everything on hover) is to add `pointer-events:none` on hovering the iframe

Comment: i did as above, but control bar is showing yet.. sad