# Can't disable controls in a youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, html5-video

I am running a content.js on a youtube page and i want it to disable the controls of the youtube video. I am getting the video by video=document.querySelector('video'); and when trying to do: video.controls=false; it does'nt work. Would love some help

[image: content.js]

here is the video tag when I run the code on youtube's console:
[image]

Comment: Youtube doesn't use the built-in controls. It shows a separate element. Inspect it in devtools, find the selector, then hide it e.g. `elem.hidden = true`

Comment: @wOxxOm , how can i disable the option that when a user presses the video it starts/pauses - with the other buttons i can hide them but i cant find the element responsble for the clicking on the video itself

Comment: Add a listener for `play` or `pause` events on the video element.

Comment: @wOxxOm ,  what do you mean by that? how can a event listener for play or pause can help me find that element in the html? If you have the code for it I will appriciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used @wOxxOm advice and figured out how to hide the play button and the timeline bar.

Here is the used code:

```
playButton=document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-play-button ytp-button")[0];
bar=document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-progress-bar-container")[0];

playButton.style.display="none";
bar.style.display="none";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let video = document.getElementById('vid');
video.removeAttribute('controls')
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column">
  Vid 1 :
  <video id="vid" controls>
    <source src="#" />
  </video>
  Vid 2 :
  <video id="vid2" controls>
    <source src="#" />
  </video>
</div>
```

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161516/html5-video-completely-hide-controls), on your `<video>` tag, you dont want to put `controls` if you don't want them 
quick example :

```
<video width="400px" height="400px" controls> // this will show controls
   <source src="link" />
</video>
<video width="400px" height="400px"> // this won't show controls
   <source src="link" />
</video>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html code you are using

Comment: I've seen this post but it dosent help me because I'm using an already exsiting video tag.

Comment: Can i see the video tag you are using ? where is the html of the `<video>`

Comment: I can't see the video tag too - because I am using a content script i just can hold the variable itself and there is not way of seeing the html in the code, plus remove Attribute doesn't work as well