# how to hide the progress bar of a video in HTML

Tags: html, css, html5-video, progress-bar, webkit

i'm try use webkit but it didn't work

```
 #videoP::-webkit-progress-value {
     display: none;
}

#videoP::-webkit-progress-bar {
    display: none;
}
```

this my video code in html

```
<video id="videoP" class="img-thumbnail" controls>
    <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

i want hide the progress bar of a video in HTML like a youtube ad.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

> *"I want to hide the progress bar of a video in HTML..."*

Maybe you want **-webkit-media-controls-timeline**?

Check if this CSS setting gives you the expected result:

```
#videoP::-webkit-media-controls-timeline 
{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36293084/17582002) to a similar question.

I think what you are looking for is this specific css pseudo-element:

```
#videoP::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  display: none;
}
```

see also the following sources:

- [Chromium -webkit mediaControls.css](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/72fef91ac1ef679207f51def8133b336a6f6588f/Source/core/css/mediaControls.css?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F)
- [Apple -webkit mediaControls.css](https://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-1640/css/mediaControls.css.auto.html)